# securing PHP code

Tags: php

I do quite large project for a client and I would like (somehow) to secure code form event that mid dishonest client was not going to pay me for the work. :)
The contract is written that the project must provide application with a sources.
So far I mostly been writing in .NET where I was protecting myself against such an eventuality in way that I was creating class witch get POST some parameters with shutdown application. This class was thrown into a dll witch was already compiled, so no one could change the source.
Is there a similar possibility in PHP? I can do the same thing (as in .NET case) but clever customers with access to PHP can find above class and I just cut it.
Maybe it is some other way to secure myself?
Suturing of the database also eliminated for similar reasons as above.

Comment: how can the client be sure you remove the malicious code after payment? :)

Comment: after payment under the pretext of refactoring code I was switching the dll files to version with no backdoor. ;) and in contract i have pargraph that full responsibiliti for code is on me. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP is an interpreted language; as a result, it doesn't compile your code. Your best bet is to stick with .NET, where you can compile the functional part of the application into a .dll, or use Java and compile it into a bytecode. 
PHP wasn't built for compiling. 
What you can do is probably host the application on your server till the client has made a payment, and then upload it to the client's server. 
Or you can make it downloadable from your server (only after payment), along with configuration scripts that is configurable by anyone with a few clicks of the button; something similar to the way some of the PHP frameworks (e.g. WordPress) work.

Comment: great! i know that PHP isn't compilable but I thought about something like the minification code. But I think your proposal to serve code from server and share it after payment is great! I didn't thought about it. thanks one more time mate! :)

Answer (score -1):

You can protect your code with Zend Guard (http://www.zend.com/en/products/guard/).

Comment: no zend will not resolv my problem becouse to decompile code I must use external env.